# Cann't receive REMOTE host log messages with Chainsaw (localhost messages just OK)

Tags: log4j, host, apache-chainsaw

I did a logger with programmatically configured SocketAppender  for Chainsaw. I successfully receive messages in the SimpleReceiver of Chainsaw from code running on localhost, but from remote host i'm just getting like

> 63    Fri Sep 23 14:44:08 MSD
>   2011  INFO    org.apache.log4j.chainsaw.messages.MessageCenter    **Connection
>   received from
>   my.host.com:50299**       Chainsaw-WorkerThread                       log chainsaw
>
> 68    Fri Sep 23 15:12:22 MSD
>   2011  INFO    org.apache.log4j.chainsaw.messages.MessageCenter    **Connection
>   lost! :: null**       Chainsaw-WorkerThread
>
> log   chainsaw 69 Fri Sep 23 15:12:22 MSD
>   2011  DEBUG   org.apache.log4j.net.SocketReceiver **accepted
>   socket**      Chainsaw-WorkerThread                       log chainsaw
>
> 70    Fri Sep 23 15:12:22 MSD
>   2011  DEBUG   org.apache.log4j.net.SocketReceiver **socket not null -
>   creating and starting**
>   socketnode        Chainsaw-WorkerThread                       log chainsaw
>
> 71    Fri Sep 23 15:12:22 MSD
>   2011  DEBUG   org.apache.log4j.net.SocketReceiver w**aiting to accept
>   socket**      Chainsaw-WorkerThread                       log chainsaw

but no tab with log messages from remote host. What's wrong? No firewall is running.
Tested with v2 and v2.1-trunk-today.

Comment: with new version it's slightly different:

Comment: 105 Mon Sep 26 19:32:44 MSD 2011  DEBUG org.apache.log4j.net.SocketReceiver accepted socket  Thread-9  org.apache.log4j.spi.Log4JULogger debug Log4JULogger.java 600148 59 chainsaw log
106 Mon Sep 26 19:32:44 MSD 2011  DEBUG org.apache.log4j.net.SocketReceiver socket not null - creating and starting socketnode  Thread-9  org.apache.log4j.spi.Log4JULogger debug Log4JULogger.java 0 59 chainsaw log
107 Mon Sep 26 19:32:44 MSD 2011  DEBUG org.apache.log4j.net.SocketReceiver waiting to accept socket  Thread-9  org.apache.log4j.spi.Log4JULogger debug Log4JULogger.java 0 59 chainsaw log

Comment: 108 Mon Sep 26 19:32:44 MSD 2011  INFO org.apache.log4j.chainsaw.messages.MessageCenter Connection received from my.remote.host:48980  Thread-20  org.apache.log4j.chainsaw.ChainsawStatusBar remoteConnectionReceived ChainsawStatusBar.java 15 232 chainsaw log
109 Mon Sep 26 19:32:44 MSD 2011  INFO org.apache.log4j.chainsaw.messages.MessageCenter Connection lost! :: null  Thread-20  org.apache.log4j.chainsaw.LogUI$36 socketClosedEvent LogUI.java 0 1268 chainsaw log

Comment: 110 Mon Sep 26 19:32:44 MSD 2011  DEBUG org.apache.log4j.net.SocketReceiver accepted socket  Thread-9  org.apache.log4j.spi.Log4JULogger debug Log4JULogger.java 0 59 chainsaw log
111 Mon Sep 26 19:32:44 MSD 2011  DEBUG org.apache.log4j.net.SocketReceiver socket not null - creating and starting socketnode  Thread-9  org.apache.log4j.spi.Log4JULogger debug Log4JULogger.java 0 59 chainsaw log

Comment: 112 Mon Sep 26 19:32:44 MSD 2011  DEBUG org.apache.log4j.net.SocketReceiver waiting to accept socket  Thread-9  org.apache.log4j.spi.Log4JULogger debug Log4JULogger.java 0 59 chainsaw log
113 Mon Sep 26 19:32:44 MSD 2011  INFO org.apache.log4j.chainsaw.messages.MessageCenter Connection received from my.remote.host:48981  Thread-21  org.apache.log4j.chainsaw.ChainsawStatusBar remoteConnectionReceived ChainsawStatusBar.java 0 232 chainsaw log

Comment: No custom configuration file *.lcf specified

Answer (score 1):

Solved yesterday. Log level in big app's plugin wasn't set correctly.